# SQL query on 3 tables with one to many relationships

Tags: mysql, sql, e-commerce

I need help on figuring out the SQL query for my e-commerce site

there are `Users`(customers / customer-service-reps) table

there are `Orders` table

there are `Line-Items`(columns are manufacturer, quantity, ect) table

Users have many Orders, and Orders have many Line-Items.

I am trying to find list of users who has made 1 or more order which includes items from ('X-Parts' <- name of manufacturer)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is very basic sql -- lookup `join` and `where` and let us know what troubles you have.

Comment: sorry didn't asnwer my question

Comment: @sgeddes If you can't explain it simply, you don't understand it well enough.
Read more at http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/a/alberteins383803.html#7VU6SblG4c8Sug6T.99

Comment: What @sgeddes is trying to say is what attempt have you made at trying to find the answer on your own. This is SQL 101. You'll never learn or pass your SQL database class by just asking for the answer.

Comment: what is your DBMS? SQL Server, MYSQL or Oracle

Comment: I studied coding briefly but I have a technical co founder as a CTO for it. Piyush our answer was actually correct I had to switch around some syntactic stuff e.g. - with _ and it worked thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT U.UserID, COUNT(O.OrderID) OrderCount
FROM Users U INNER JOIN Orders O ON U.UserID = O.UserID
             INNER JOIN Line-Items L ON O.OrderID = L.OrderID
Where L.manufacturer = 'X-Parts'
Group BY U.UserID
Having count(O.orderID) >= 1
```

Sample Demo:- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f1712/2

Comment: sorry there is a syntax error for this answer it says

Comment: just needed some adjustments for naming conventions for MySql thanks a bunch Piyush

Answer (score 0):

```
Its one or more orders.

SELECT U.UserID, COUNT(O.OrderID) as OrderCount
FROM Users U 
INNER JOIN Orders O ON U.UserID = O.UserID
INNER JOIN Line-Items L ON O.OrderID = L.OrderID
Where L.manufacturer = 'X-Parts'
Group BY U.UserID
Having count(O.orderID) >= 1
```

Comment: also sorry there is a syntax error for this answer it says